# Gedit icon detaches from the dash, if using custom actions in its desktop file

Tags: launcher, unity-dash, gedit

One of the features I've missed in Windows 7 is that you can pin your favourite files to the application icon's right click menu. Luckily, I've since discovered, that you can create so called "actions" in a particular application's desktop file, so you can access your desired files by right clicking on the application icon by adding the following lines to the .desktop file:

```
Actions=Action1;Action2;Action3;

[Desktop Action Action 1]
Name=Name which appears in right click menu
Exec=gedit "path/to/file"
OnlyShowIn=Unity

[Desktop Action Action 2]
...
```

And so on.

However, upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 while this works with other application icons, with Gedit now it doesn't behave accordingly. Unless I open the application beforehand, using the right click menu items detaches the Gedit task icon from the dash locked icon. Image:

[image: This is what it looks:]

The upper one is the locked dash icon, accessible by SUPER-9, and the lower one is what opened when clicked on the one of the right click items of the dash locked icon. Because of that, I can't switch to gedit with the SUPER-9 keystroke, it creates a new document in it instead.

Comment: Which one did you edit, the original one in `/usr/share/applications`, or a local copy in `~/.local/share/applications`. Also Please [edit] and add the output of both: `find /usr/share/applications -name *gedit*` and `find ~/.local/share/applications -name *gedit*`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the `xdg-open` instead of `gedit` in the Exec command of the action. Example:

```
[Desktop Action Action 1]
Name=My bookmarks
Exec=xdg-open "Documents/my_bookmarks"
OnlyShowIn=Unity
```

Tip: if you want to open more than one files with a right-click menu, you can't do it directly in the desktop file because `xdg-open` doesn't allow opening multiple files in one command. You have to make a shell script, with a for loop, like this:

```
#!bin/sh
for i in "Documents/document 1.txt" "Documents/document 2.txt"; do
   xdg-open "$i"
done
```

Put the script in your scripts directory, and use that in your desktop action's Exec line.

Comment: This answer makes no sense.  Like you posted it, it cannot possibly work. Furthermore; apart from the typo(s)  in the `Exec=` line, the cause is a totally different one.

Comment: Why wouldn't work? Changing `gedit` to `xdg-open` in the actions solved the issue for me. However I've noticed the `Exec` typos, so I've fixed it.